# How to cancel pending Win8 to Win8.1 upgrade?

Tags: windows, windows-8, upgrade

I am a Windows 8 user and, for some reasons, I don't want to upgrade it to Windows 8.1. I would get an annoying pop-up window from time to time, offering me a free upgrade. I would always turn down the offer ('No, thanks' button or sth like this) and forget about it till the next pop-up appeared.
Suddenly, 4 days ago... surprise! Another pop-up window, this time with a different message. Don't remember the exact words, but it went somewhat like this:

> 'Your Windows 8 has been upgraded to Windows 8.1! Restart your
>   computer to apply the changes, it may take 30-45 minutes (....) Your
>   computer will automatically restart in 4 days.'

and a few options to choose:

> 'Restart now / restart in 1/2/4 hours / remind me later'.

**WAT.** 
I don't want Win 8.1 and never agreed for an upgrade. Told it to remind me later, thinking that they have just changed the text of an offer and won't install an upgrade without my permission anyway. However, I would be getting this message every day, with

> 'your computer will automatically restart in 3/2/1 days'.

I checked pending updates in my Windows Update - there were a few updates with 'needs restart' status, but none of them seemed to have anything to do with Windows upgrade. Then... I forgot about this problem and restarted my computer for the first time since the message appeared for the first time. Restarted my computer and immediately reminded myself of the situation. Panicked. Yet... nothing happened to my Windows 8 after the restart, it was still 8, not 8.1. All the updates in Windows Update changed their status to 'installed', so definitely none of them was causing an upgrade. But! I got another message telling me to restart my computer in order to finish the upgrade to 8.1, this time with no 'remind me later' option. Just

> 'restart now or in 1/2/4 hours'.

Okaaay... 
Picked 4 hours. Disabled automatic restart on my computer so it won't take place. However, i cannot keep my computer without restart forever. The questions are...

- Why didn't the restart of my computer affect this upgrade and it would still tell me to restart having already done it?
- **Where to search for this pending update and how to prevent it from happening as it is not seen in Windows Update updates and I can't cancel it there?**
- Least important, but why the hell did my Windows 8 decide to upgrade without my permission to do so?

Comment: Why are you against upgrading; at this point it's to late to cancel it; and yes you at some point agreed to it; it's the only way your in this situation

Comment: Well, no changes have been applied yet, they must have been just downloaded and queued for appliance at a later time. Therefore, I believe those files must be stored somewhere on my disc and it has to be possible to delete them or prevent from being applied.

Comment: **Least important, but why the hell did my Windows 8 decide to upgrade without my permission to do so?** because of this update: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3008273/en-us